# getting the size of a window or panel in MFC C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, size

How can I get the **size** of a "window" or a "panel" in MFC C++?
is there a function or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [`CWnd::GetWindowRect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3ef9c0s.aspx):

```
CWnd  wnd; // the window to query
CRect wndrect;

wnd.GetWindowRect(wndrect);
```

And from there you can get

```
int w = wndrect.Width ();
int h = wndrect.Height();
```

This will work for all kinds of MFC windows because all MFC window classes inherit `CWnd`.